# php file upload - update tehniques

Tags: php, file-upload, updatemodel

Guys and Girls I have the following problem: I want to let my users update and delete the files they have uploaded before to an entity.

ok suppose we have:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="filefield" type="file">
    <input name="submitfield" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I have no problems saving the file on the server and showing the file back to the users. But I don't know how to let my users change(update) the file if they decide that.

```
<input type="file">
```

fields don't act as

```
 <input type="text">
```

fields where I can compare the value I had before with the new value and determine if the value has changed and do the update in the storage.

How do you handle update and removal of files especially for those that are referenced by another object. Lets say you have a blog entity and that blog entity can have attached pictures.

Thank you!

Comment: same upload, but try to find out previous image path and remove that using `unlink` before uploading new one.

Comment: if i have an array of files <input name="userfiles[]"> how do i know witch file was changed? if its only 1 file I check to see if I have got another one and if so I delete the old one and copy the new one instead sure you are right and maybe on in the browser I let the <input type="file"> with javascript only when the users clicks a change link even so how do I know if the wants the file removed  and the big problem I have is with array of files

Comment: at a time how many files user can upload as a profile pic?

Comment: i want to allow then for example to add as many pictures as they want I have a javascript code that adds <input type="file" name="filefield[]"> added to a buttendevent when clicked. Thats not a problem to save all of them on the server I can do that what i don't know is if the user decides to change his profile I want him to have to possibility to delete or change some of the pictures that he uploaded before maybe also to upload new (I know how to handle this) But for the others I dont know how to keep a reference in the <form> with the files on the server thats my problem

Comment: when user going to upload image try to upload them with some incremented id wise.When user go to his profile show them all and when user select them based on that id remove them.

Comment: But better idea is upload one profile image at a time. otherwise burden of images will increase

Comment: I told you I dont have a problem with the upload I have a probelm when I want to update(change) or delete one of the files I uploaded before especially change cause I don't know how to send a reference back to the server(php) in the <input type="file"> so I don't know on the server what file has changed I was thinking to pass the file_id as the key of the  array  in that way I can examine on the server what keys are new or what keys have new content althou I'm not sure this is the best way to do it...Hope others do it much cleaner